# Ordenar um array multidimensional com valores numéricos

Tags: php, array, algoritmo, array-multidimensional, classificação

Suponhamos a seguinte situação na qual tenho um `array` composto por vários `array` com valores numéricos:

```
$array = array(
    array(22, 25, 28),
    array(22),
    array(22, 23)
)
```

Gostaria de deixar este `array` ordenado da seguinte forma:

```
$array = array(
    array(22),
    array(22, 23),
    array(22, 25, 28)
)
```

Qual seria o algoritmo para este caso?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Utilize a função [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.asort.php):

> Essa função ordena um array de forma que a correlação entre índices e valores é mantida. É usada principalmente para ordenar arrays associativos onde a ordem dos elementos é um fator importante.

**Exemplo:**

```
$array = array(
   array(22, 25, 28),
   array(22),
   array(22, 23)
);

asort($array);
```

**Resultado:**

```
var_dump($array);

array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(22)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(22)
    [1]=>
    int(23)
  }
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(22)
    [1]=>
    int(25)
    [2]=>
    int(28)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```php
array_multisort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Qualquer coisa procura alguma coisa por aqui:
[Link](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma também seria utilizando a função `uasort`, onde você ordena o `array`de acordo com um callback passado. Utilizamos `count` nos `array` comparados internamente do `callback` para determinar qual é a posição que será ordenada.

Imaginemos o seguinte `array`:

```
$a = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 3,
    2 => 4,
    3 => 5,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 3,
  ),
);
```

Poderíamos ordená-lo da seguinte forma:

```
 uasort($a, function ($a, $b) { 
     return count($a) - count($b);
 })
```

O resultado seria:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 3,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 3,
    2 => 4,
    3 => 5,
  ),
)
```

Se você quisesse esse resultado em ordem reversa, poderia fazer assim:

```
 uasort($a, function ($a, $b) { 
     return count($b) - count($a);
 })

 print_r($a);
```

O resultado seria:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 3,
    2 => 4,
    3 => 5,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 3,
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
  ),
)
```