# Agrupar, atribuir e ordenar valores de um array multidimensional em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, array, matriz

Olá, pessoal. Tenho o seguinte array multidimensional em PHP:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => teste0 [1] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => teste1 [1] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => teste2 [1] => 2 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => teste3 [1] => 2 )
[4] => Array ( [0] => teste4 [1] => 2 )
[5] => Array ( [0] => teste5 [1] => 3 )
[6] => Array ( [0] => teste6 [1] => 4 )
[7] => Array ( [0] => teste7 [1] => 4 )
)
```

Gostaria de rankear esse array de acordo com a quantidade de valores iguais que estão no valor [1] (numérico). Isso produziria o seguinte resultado:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => teste2 [1] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => teste3 [1] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => teste4 [1] => 1 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => teste0 [1] => 2 )
[4] => Array ( [0] => teste1 [1] => 2 )
[5] => Array ( [0] => teste6 [1] => 4 )
[6] => Array ( [0] => teste7 [1] => 4 )
[7] => Array ( [0] => teste5 [1] => 3 )
)
```

Como fazer esse rankeamento utilizando PHP ou Javascript?

Comment: Por quê sumiu um "teste2" do primeiro para o segundo exemplo e apareceu um "teste1"?

Comment: Utilize a função `array_multisort`

Comment: Se é pela quantidade de valores iguais, não devia aparecer o valor `2` primeiro ? Esse é o que tem mais "ocorrências".

Comment: Você quer ordenar, é isso?

Comment: Dá uma [olhada aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136759/ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-todos-os-elementos-de-uma-matriz-array-multidimensional), e veja se te ajuda. Me ajudou.

Comment: Nesse caso, no primeiro array, como o valor 2 é o que mais se repete, ele se torna o novo primeiro colocado. O resultado é os seus elementos recebendo o valor 1 no array resultado.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nessa função e no link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que me parece mais facil para resolver o seu problema é criar um array com as contagens de cada elemento e depois ordendar com base nas contagens.

Para a criação das contagens, pode criar um array vazio e ir somando cada elemento que apanha em relação à posição `1` do sub-array:

```
$contagens = Array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $subArr){
    $val = $subArr[1];
    $contagens[$val] = isset($contagens[$val]) ? $contagens[$val] + 1 : 1;
}
```

Que para o array apresentado na pergunta dá o seguinte resultado:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
)
```

Depois pode ordenar utilizando a função [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php), que permite passar uma função de comparação com a lógica que nós queremos. No seu caso pode comparar pelas contagens, e quando as contagens são iguais, pelo próprio número em si:

```
usort($arr, function ($a,$b) use ($contagens){
  return $contagens[$a[1]]==$contagens[$b[1]] ? $a[1]-$b[1]: $contagens[$b[1]]-$contagens[$a[1]];
});
```

Repare que tive de utilizar `use` para poder fazer uso do array de contagens achado previamente.

Após isto o array final fica assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => teste4
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => teste2
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => teste3
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => teste0
            [1] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => teste1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => teste6
            [1] => 4
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => teste7
            [1] => 4
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => teste5
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

[Veja este exmeplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ND2NCh)